# jquery datatable how to parse and add row from MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

OK I have the following

```
function AddSpellRow() {
    var row = $('.tbl_spells').dataTable().fnGetData(0);
    $('.tbl_spells').dataTable().fnAddData(row);
}
```

which add  this  row

```
<tr class="odd">

   <td class="">    
     <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Spells_0__Id" name="Spells[0].Id" type="hidden" value="4"> 

     <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Spells_0__Spell_Id" name="Spells[0].Spell.Id" class="valid">
       <option value="">---Select --</option> 
       <option value="1">Rains</option> 
     </select>

   </td>

   <td class="">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PriestLevel must be a number." data-val-required="The PriestLevel field is required." id="Spells_0__PriestLevel" name="Spells[0].PriestLevel" type="text" value="10" class="valid">
   </td>

</tr>
```

How do i change [0] and underscore0underscore with [#of rows]  and underscorenumber of rowsunderscore ?

Also i need the type="hidden" value="4" with type="hidden" value="0"

i tried replace on row and it doesnt like it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use fnAddData

```
    var otable = $('.tbl_spells').dataTable();
    var row = otable.fnGetData(0),
    row_count = otable.fnGetData().length;

    var addId = otable.fnAddData(row);
    var newRow = otable.fnSettings().aoData[addId[0]].nTr;

    var theNode =  $(newRow.cells[0])  ;
    $(theNode[0].children[0]).attr('id', 'Spells_' + row_count + '__Id');
    $(theNode[0].children[0]).attr('name', 'Spells[' + row_count + '].Id');
    $(theNode[0].children[0]).attr('value', 0 );

    $(theNode[0].children[1]).attr('id', 'Spells_' + row_count + '__Spell_Id');
    $(theNode[0].children[1]).attr('name', 'Spells[' + row_count + '].Spell.Id');

    theNode = $(newRow.cells[1]);
    $(theNode[0].children[0]).attr('id', 'Spells_' + row_count + '__PriestLevel');
    $(theNode[0].children[0]).attr('name', 'Spells[' + row_count + '].PriestLevel');
```